# Retrieving Arrays from <ReferenceInput> and <SelectInput>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm doing a project and I'm using React Admin to make the admin interface and FireStore which is the database. My problem is that I would like to make a `<ReferenceInput>` and a `<SelectInput>` to select data entered in an `<ArrayInput>` and I can't find how to do it.

Here is the code with the `<ArrayInput>`:

```js
export const TeamsCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props} >
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source='teamName'/>
            <ArrayInput source="teamMembers">
                <SimpleFormIterator inline >
                    <TextInput source='teamMembersName' placeholder='Name' helperText={false}/>
                    <TextInput source='teamMembersSurname' placeholder='Surname' helperText={false}/>
                    <RadioButtonGroupInput source="teamMembersRole" choices={[
                        { id: 'climber', name: 'climber' },
                        { id: 'judges', name: 'judges' },
                    ]} />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ArrayInput>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

And here is my code where I want to retrieve the data from the teamMembers Array (I would like to retrieve all the first names of the people who are judges)

```js
export const SectorCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props} >
        <SimpleForm>
            <NumberInput source='Sector Number' />
            <RadioButtonGroupInput source="Sector Type" choices={[
                { id: 'boulder', name: 'boulder' },
                { id: 'difficulty', name: 'difficulty' },
                { id: 'speed', name: 'speed' },
            ]} />
      <ReferenceInput label="Judge" source="teamMembers" reference="Teams">
        <SelectInput optionText="teamMembers" />
      </ReferenceInput>
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
)
```

I've done quite a few tests, and so far I'm only getting [Object object]
[Screenshot with what the selection shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHBEN.png)

I also tried it like this:

```js
export const SectorCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props} >
        <SimpleForm>
            <NumberInput source='Sector Number' />
            <RadioButtonGroupInput source="Sector Type" choices={[
                { id: 'boulder', name: 'boulder' },
                { id: 'difficulty', name: 'difficulty' },
                { id: 'speed', name: 'speed' },
            ]} />
      <ReferenceInput label="Judge" source="teamMembers[teamMembersName]" reference="Teams">
        <SelectInput optionText="teamMembers[teamMembersName]" />
      </ReferenceInput>
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
)
```

If anyone has a solution I'd love it :)